# Count occurences in every Xth column for another certain value

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to make a summary table where I display a count for another table.

I have a data source, where different activities assigned to different people. Each week they report by `YES` / `NO` / `N/A` according to whether they completed certain paperwork for their assigned projects.

I would like to COUNT how many `YES`s and `NO`s (for example) `Anna` has for Updated Sched for 4 weeks for all her Projects.

Is there a shorter simpler formula I could use instead of doing it like this?:

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:C27,C32,D:D,"YES")+COUNTIFS(C1:C27,C32,D:D,"NO")+ same for every 3rd column
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach? Instead of combining all the data into the respective cells, take it in steps that allow copying of formulae. So for example, in D32, copied down five rows and these across to suit:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$27,$C32,D$1:D$27,"YES")
```

(assumes the second block in your example has the names moved one column to the right). Then copy C32:C36 into C38 and D32 into D38, change `YES` to `NO` and copy again as above.

Then copy C32:C36 into C44 and in D44:

```
 =D32+D38
```

again copied down five rows and across to suit.

Then add every third column to suit and hide rows 28 to 48.